# Finding a a specific value in a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I need some help editing my code to give me a single output using boolean values. True or False.

I have a code which I wrote which searchs through a 2d array to find of any values which >=32.
But currently it loops through and gives an answer for each value. I'm just looking for a single output that if a value is equal to 32 or more then true. If no such value if found then false.

My code is

```
grid = [[2, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 8],
        [0, 16, 0, 128],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]
a = np.array(grid)
for row in grid:
    for c in row:
        if c >= 32:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to set a true/false flag in the loop, and then print the flag after the loop is all done.

```
grid = [[2, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 8],
        [0, 16, 0, 128],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]
flag = False
for row in grid:
    for c in row:
        if c >= 32:
            flag = True
            break
print(flag)
```

Comment: Thanks so much this was a huge help

Answer (score 2):

To see if there are any values greater than 32:

```py
(np.array(grid) > 32).any()
```

```
True
```

To get the indices:

```py
np.where(np.array(grid) > 32)
```

```
(array([2], dtype=int64), array([3], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
grid_array = np.array(grid)
print(np.any(grid_array >= 32))
```

Answer (score 1):

Non numpy version:

```
print(any([x>=32 for y in grid for x in y]))
# True
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Import Numpy:

   import numpy as np
2. Declare your array:

   x = np.array[[2, 0, 2, 0],
   [0, 4, 0, 8],
   [0, 16, 0, 128],
   [2, 2, 2, 2]]

   x > 32
3. Verify the result:

   x

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing every time you check for value you can add print statement at the end of the loop -

```
grid = [[2, 0, 2, 0],
    [0, 4, 0, 8],
    [0, 16, 0, 128],
    [2, 2, 2, 2]]
isTrue = False
for row in grid:
  for c in row:
    if c >= 32:
        isTrue = True

print(isTrue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Example without `numpy` using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) so no nested loop:

```
from itertools import chain

grid = [[2, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 8],
        [0, 16, 0, 128],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]

print(any(x >= 32 for x in chain.from_iterable(grid)))
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
import numpy as np
grid = [[2, 0, 2, 0],
        [0, 4, 0, 8],
        [0, 16, 0, 128],
        [2, 2, 2, 2]]
a = np.array(grid)
ix = np.where(a>=32)
```

You will get the row and column, where the value is larger than 32.